# Is there a way to have Windows 8 perform automatic image and file backup of different folders to different drives?

Tags: windows-8, windows-backup

I have several 2 TB drives that have almost 2 TB of unique data each (well more than 1 TB each) and lots of available backup drives for Windows 8 Pro 64.

When I use the File Backup in Control Panel and go to Settings, I can select the data from the C drive and then video from another drive and music and photos from another drive, all to be backed up.

But, it wants to put all of these file Backups and also a system image on one drive. But, I have no drive large enough to take all the backup.

Is there a way to specify a different drive to receive the file backup of the video, then of the photos, etc and then of the image of the C drive?

The result would be an automated backup and image creation that would be dispersed over four different drives.

Comment: Windows 8 has built-in support for this.  The feature is called Storage Spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "Windows 7 File Recovery" option in Control Panel to schedule system images and store them in a different location from where you store "File History" backups.

You can also use PowerShell to script this stuff out so you have finer control over things. Then you can use Task Scheduler to schedule when the PowerShell scripts trigger.

You can get sample PowerShell scripts for backups at the TechNet Scripting Center -

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=backup&f%5B0%5D.Text=Backup%20and%20System%20Restore